# Automatically copy data from Google sheets to Google docs template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I need to automatically populate a Google docs template  each time someone submits a Google form. I've got the Google sheet with all of the information and I've got the template docs set up with the areas i want to populate but I can't find anywhere that shows how to do what I need to.

Can anyone share the knowledge please?

Comment: That's a possibility.  Please provide more details about you template.

Comment: The template Is for a quote. I'm trying to copy over the first name, surname, address, phone number and email. I'm also trying to get sheets to generate a reference number but i can't get it work when the data is populated on the sheet from the submission form.

Comment: Well it looks like you already have an answer please work with the volunteer to resolve any further issues.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is ['Auto Fill Google Doc From Form'](https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2018/09/17/auto-fill-google-doc-from-google-form-submission/).    You will need to add a function to your sheet, with a trigger of onFormSubmit. In that function, you will

- reference your template
- create a new doc off that template
- generate a reference number
- update the new doc with the information

It will look something like this:

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
     // Get your values from form
     let timestamp = e.values[0];
     let value1 = e.values[1];
     let value2 = e.values[2];
     // ... continue for however many values you are returning

     // Get your template file
     let templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById('your_file_id_here');

     // Set the folder you want to create the new file in
     let responseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('your_folder_id_for_new_doc'); 

     // Create your reference number
     let refNumber = createReferenceNumber();  // You'll need to write this

     // Create your new file
     let newDocName = createNewDocFileName();  // You'll need to write this
     let copy = file.makeCopy(newDocName , responseFolder); 
     
     // Open the newly created document so it can be updated
     let doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 

     // Update the doc with your new data
     let body = doc.getBody();

     // The template should have placeholders {{ }} to replace the value with
     body.replaceText('{{value1}}', value1); 
     body.replaceText('{{value2}}', value2);  
     body.replaceText('{{Reference Number}}', refNumber); 

     doc.saveAndClose();  
}
```

Of course, you'll need to write a script to create the reference number, and a script for the filename generation. (Or just add them in-line, they don't have to be separate scripts.)  Your question mentioned that you are having trouble generating a reference number.  I recommend creating a new question that has the code you've tried & any errors you are receiving.